# ApplicationResources.properties file is not loaded using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring MVC appliation designing multiple layers Controller ---> Service ----> Model ----> DAO classes. My requirement is to put all labels of JSP pages as part of properties file and use this as part of my jsp page.

I have created a folder called com --> mytest --> test --> resources --> ApplicationResources.properties file. As part of my Controller Iam using like this:

```
 @PropertySource("/com/mytest/test/resources/ApplicationResources.properties")
 @Controller
 public class CreateController {
```

My issue is unable to load this file so I have added this as part of my Java build path. Then it stopped generating resources folder as part of WEB-INF/classes folder. My issue is still remaining with below exception:

```
 Failed to load bean class: com.mytest.test.controller.CreateController; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/mytest/test/resources/ApplicationResources.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Even if i remove this from Controller and use this as part of my jsp is giving issue:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
 <fmt:bundle basename="com.mytest.test.resources.ApplicationResources">
```

Displaying labels like this ???title???. Please help resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@PropertySource` isn't for i18n but for the application settings so it won't work. AFAIR you need something like `messageSource` bean (but I'm not sure that `<fmt:bundle>` will use it either.

Comment: First `@PropertySource` should on a `@Configuration` class not on `@Controller` classes. Second the file should reside in the `src/main/resources` folder and not in `src/main/java` or `src/main/webapp` (in the `java` folder it will be ignored, and in the `webapp` folder it isn't part of the class path). And finally doing I18N should be done using a [`MessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource) and not proper integration with spring in your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `@PropertySource`, that should be on a `@Configuration` class not on `@Controller` classes.

To put all labels of JSP pages as part of properties file and use this as part of jsp page, you need to follow the steps:

1. configure properties file in spring-servlet.xml (spring configuration file).

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
```

2. Put properties file in classpath(src/main/resources folder).

and write the level in key, value pair in application file.

Ex:

```
msg.username=Username
msg.password=Password
```

3. In JSP page

As i have used in our application its working fine.